# How can I set the npm version in gitlab CI?

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab pipeline for an Angular project with the image in `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: node:16


build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm ci
    - nodejs -v
    - npm -v
    - npm run build:prod
    - npm doctor
```

When the pipeline reaches the `npm doctor` it fails with the following error on npm version:

```
$ npm doctor
Check                               Value   Recommendation/Notes
npm ping                            ok
npm -v                              not ok  Use npm v7.24.0
node -v                             ok      current: v16.9.1, recommended: v16.9.1
npm config get registry             ok      using default registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/)
which git                           ok      /usr/bin/git
Perms check on cached files         ok
Perms check on local node_modules   ok
Perms check on global node_modules  ok
Perms check on local bin folder     ok
Perms check on global bin folder    ok
Verify cache contents               ok      verified 1361 tarballs
```

How can I solve this?

In my machine I have the npm version v7.24.0 and the command succeeds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install npm before you do anything else, specifying a version, i.e. `npm install npm@version -g`.

For completeness, if you can't update the global npm, you can do so locally, by replacing `npm` with `npx npm@latest` or `npx npm@7.24.0`.  `npx` will install npm if it needs to, *locally*, and then run the local installation.

Lastly you can install locally with `npm install npm@latest` and then run it with `$(npm bin)/npm`, but this is what `npx` is for.

Note that I don't understand why you're running npm doctor *after* a build.  Presumably if you care about npm thining it's set up properly you should run it *before* the build, so the pipeline fails early.

P.S. I stupidly read 'github' as 'gitlab'. If you were using github I would recommend using
[setup-node](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) if only for dependency caching, which can seriously speed up pipelines.  I don't know if gitlab does anything similar.

Comment: I added `npm install npm@7.24.0` before the `npm doctor` and then `npm ci`, but it keeps throwing the same error on `npm -v`. Also I am looking for `setup-node` for gitlab.

Comment: sorry, for the systemwide you need `-g`.  I can't remember whether you can do that in the gitlab ci env.  Otherwise you can run the local npm.

Comment: edited to cover the local installation case.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked with -g option! 
the npx option didn't